# Change CSS of li tag which is inside div and ul tag : jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, menu

This is my menu. I am using Metro UI template.

```
<div id="divMenu" class="fluent-menu" data-role="fluentmenu" data-on-special-click="specialClick">
    <ul class="tabs-holder">
    <li id="litabhome" class="active"><a href="#tab_home">Home</a></li>
    <li id="litabmailings" class=""><a href="#tab_mailings">Mailing</a></li>
    <li id="litabfolder" class=""><a href="#tab_folder">Folder</a></li>
    <li id="litabview" class=""><a href="#tab_view">View</a></li>
    <li id="limasters" class="active"><a href="#tab_masters">Masters</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-content">
    <div class="tab-panel" id="tab_home" style="display: block;">
    <div class="tab-panel-group">
    <div class="tab-group-content">
       <button class="fluent-big-button">
       <span class="icon mif-envelop"></span>
       Create<br />
       message
       </button>
     <div class="tab-content-segment">
     <button class="fluent-big-button dropdown-toggle">
    <span class="icon mif-file-picture"></span>
    <span class="label">Create<br />
       element</span>
    </button>
      <ul class="d-menu" data-role="dropdown" style="display: none;">
    <li><a href="#">Message</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Meeting</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
     <div class="tab-content-segment">
     <button class="fluent-big-button">
     <span class="mif-cancel"></span>
      <span class="label">Delete</span>
      </button>
    </div>
   </div>
     <div class="tab-group-caption">Clipboard</div>
     </div>
    <div class="tab-panel-group">
        <div class="tab-group-content">
      <div class="tab-content-segment">
   <button class="fluent-button"><span class="mif-loop"></span>Replay</button>
                                                            <button class="fluent-button"><span class="mif-infinite"></span>Replay all</button>
                                                            <button class="fluent-button"><span class="mif-loop2"></span>Forward</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="tab-content-segment">
                                                            <button class="fluent-tool-button">
                                                                <img src="MetroCSS/docs/images/Notebook-Save.png" /></button>
                                                            <button class="fluent-tool-button">
                                                                <img src="MetroCSS/docs/images/Folder-Rename.png" /></button>
                                                            <button class="fluent-tool-button">
                                                                <img src="MetroCSS/docs/images/Calendar-Next.png" /></button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="tab-group-caption">Reply</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tab-panel-group">
                                                    <div class="tab-group-content">
                                                        <div class="input-control text">
                                                            <input type="text" />
                                                            <button class="button"><span class="mif-search"></span></button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <button class="fluent-button"><span class="icon-book on-left"></span>Address Book</button>
                                                        <div class="tab-content-segment">
                                                            <button class="fluent-button dropdown-toggle">
                                                                <span class="mif-filter on-left"></span>
                                                                <span class="label">Mail Filters</span>
                                                            </button>
                                                            <ul class="d-menu" data-role="dropdown">
                                                                <li><a href="#">Unread messages</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Has attachments</a></li>
                                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Important</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Broken</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="tab-group-caption">Search</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
<div class="tab-panel" id="tab_masters" style="display: none;">
                                                <div class="tab-panel-group">
                                                    <div class="tab-group-content">
                                                        <button class="fluent-big-button" id="btnStoreMaster">
                                                            <span class="icon mif-envelop"></span>
                                                            Store Master
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
</div>
                                    </div>
```

When page loads, by default "Home" menu is showing with its content tab "tab_home".

Here, I have a tab content called "tab_masters" which has a button called 'btnStoreMaster". When user clicks this button, then it will be redirected to StoreMaster.aspx page.

Its redirecting, but its corresponding menu "Masters" is not highlighting. Again it shows the Home menu tab contents. How to make the focus in the clicked menu using JQuery or JavaScript?

This is my jQuery function,

```
$("#btnStoreMaster").click(function () {
       $("#divMenu ul li").each(function () {
            //alert($(this).attr("id"));
            if ($(this).attr("id") == "limasters") {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
            else
                $(this).removeClass("active");
        })

        $("#divMenu div").each(function () {
            alert(this.value);
            if ($(this).attr("id") == "tab_masters")
                $(this).css("display", "block");
            else
                $(this).css("display", "none");
        })
    });
```

Here, the menu css has changed, But I could not change its corresponding tab content display to block.

Comment: you need to store the state of the meniu item clicked

Comment: I am using the below code during btnStoreMaster click function
 $("#divMenu ul li").each(function () {
                //alert($(this).attr("id"));
                if ($(this).attr("id") == "limasters")
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                else
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
            }) But still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by using the below code:

```
$("#divMenu > ul li").each(function () {
     if ($(this).attr("id") == "limasters") {
     $(this).addClass("active");
     }
     else {
       $(this).removeClass("active");}
})

$("#divMenu > div > .tab-panel").each(function () {
     if ($(this).attr("id") == "tab_masters") {
         $(this).css("display", "block");
     }
     else {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
     }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

use this jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
var url = window.location.pathname,
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$"); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case trailing slash wasn't present there
// now grab every link from the navigation
$('#divMenu a').each(function () {
    // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
    if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});});
```

its take the location of current page and for each a tag if href equals location set active class
but you can already use this:

```
$(function () {
$("#btnStoreMaster").click(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname,
        urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$"); 
    $('#divMenu a').each(function () {

        if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
            $(this).addClass('active');

            $("#divMenu div").each(function () {
                alert(this.value);
                if ($(this).attr("id") == "tab_masters"){
                    $(this).css("display", "block");
                }
                else{
                    $(this).css("display", "none");
                }

            })
        }
    })
})
```

i just adjudge you need

```
$("#divMenu div").each(function () {
                alert(this.value);
                if ($(this).attr("id") == "tab_masters"){
                    $(this).css("display", "block");
                }
                else{
                    $(this).css("display", "none");
                }

            })
```

to do something.
this new cod will executing when clicking on tab, take the location or current page(StoreMaster.aspx) ,set active class and do what you want! 
hope it work for you.

Comment: $("#divMenu ul li").each(function () {
                //alert($(this).attr("id"));
                if ($(this).attr("id") == "limasters") {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                }
                else
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
            })
$("#divMenu div").each(function () {
                alert(this.value);
                if ($(this).attr("id") == "tab_masters")
                    $(this).css("display", "block");
                else
                    $(this).css("display", "none");
            }) Here,Menu css changed not tabcontent

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Its coming and again loading the default master page. ie. Home tab is selected as active and its tab content.

Comment: remove inline css   `class="active"` from your **<li>** tag and try again. if it not working use another way!  maybe there is some java code in your pages that not matching with my solution. or maybe i miss something. hope you finally find it!

Comment: search this term **how to set active class for current page on menu item**

Comment: your code not working because the java code executing in the home page(after clicking and before redirecting ) and you want to change css in other page(StoreMaster page )